# How to count values from column whilst taking into account a qty column

Tags: mysql

I've already seen other questions like this but never where an extra column is used

Say i've got this table

```
name  |   qty
nup       1
foo       1
foo       3
tup       2
foo       1
nup       4
```

In this example I would like to ge a result like

```
name  |  qty
foo      5
tup      2 
nup      5
```

At the moment i have this done up but it does not take into account the qty

```
$sql = "SELECT  `name`,COUNT(*) as count FROM Orders GROUP BY `name` ORDER BY count DESC";
```

Comment: Is there any ordering specific ordering you wanted?  You are ordering but your sample output is basically unordered.  It almost seems from your query you want sum(qty) ordered by count(name) (ie num of occurrences of each name) but that doesn't jive w your sample output.  Otherwise see above

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT name, SUM(qty) as qty FROM Orders GROUP BY name ORDER BY qty DESC";
```